# How to add data from local storage to cart?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am trying to set the cart data from local storage and set it on cart items. I have already set cart data on local storage. But I am facing issues when I am trying to set the data of local storage into the cart. When I tried to set it I can't properly set it there. Maybe that's the issue I'm facing.
Here's the cart reducer code

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { SHOW_HIDE_CART, ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_ITEM } from "../Types";
const CartReducer = (state, action) => {
  const cartDataFromLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItem');
  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_HIDE_CART: {
      return {
        ...state,
        showCart: !state.showCart,
      };
    }
    case ADD_TO_CART: {
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: [...state.cartItems, action.payload],
  
      };
    }
    case REMOVE_ITEM: {
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: state.cartItems.filter(
          (item) => item._id !== action.payload
        ),
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default CartReducer;
```

**Here's the code of Cart State**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { SHOW_HIDE_CART, ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_ITEM } from "../Types";


const CartReducer = (state, action) => {
  const cartDataFromLocal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItem'))


  switch (action.type) {
    case SHOW_HIDE_CART: {
      return {
        ...state,
        showCart: !state.showCart,
      };
    }
    case ADD_TO_CART: {
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: [...state.cartItems, action.payload],
  
      };
    }
    case REMOVE_ITEM: {
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: state.cartItems.filter(
          (item) => item._id !== action.payload
        ),
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default CartReducer;
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not saw that you use `cartDataFromLocal` variable anywhere after, you need to dispatch the action previously with the content of the local storage in your payload:

```
// in component
dispatch(addItemToCart(cartDataFromLocal));

// in actions
const addItemToCart = (cartDataFromLocal) => (dispatch) => {
   dispatch({
      type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
      payload: cartDataFromLocal
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. Still I can't fix it. I just did the codes from a tutorial and never used dispatch. Your answer maybe right but I don't know exactly how to implement them.

Comment: no problem, anyway pass the code of the component where you are making the action, and maybe i can help you better, but I understand that you can not change the state without dispatching an action. How are you saying to the reducer function which action type must to execute? where you are passing the action payload?